# ggplot2 bar-chart order by values of one group

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to order a barplot in ggplot. 
I am trying to do one of these side-by-side bar plots. I have data for 2 groups and I would like to sort the plot by the values of one group. At the moment, my plot looks like this:

[image: Example barplot]

I would like to achieve this:

[image: Expected plot]

Where the plot is ordered by the decreasing values of group 1 (here blue). 
How do I do that? I tried fct_reorder on the Category within the groups, arrange, sort, order, managed to order it outside of ggplot but it didn't come out that way... any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: 
According to the suggestions I tried the following:

```
data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_rev(fct_reorder(labels, value)), y = value, fill 
  = variable)) +
   geom_bar(stat="identity", width=.5, position = "dodge")  +
   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

and I got:

[image: Result Plot]

Which is not really what I want. I want to sort by selected (the red bars) in descending order. Selected and new are obviously one variable, so in one column. If I have to separate them thats fine, I just dont know how.

Data:

```
structure(list(labels = c("3", "16", 
                      "20", "15", "2", 
                      "11", "19", 
                      "8", "1", 
                      "9", "12", "14", 
                      "22", "6", "5", 
                      "18", "17", "23", 
                      "21", "13", "7", 
                      "10", "4", "3", "16", 
                      "20", "15", "2", 
                      "11", "19", 
                      "8", "1", 
                      "9", "12", "14", 
                      "22", "6", "5", 
                      "18", "17", "23", 
                      "21", "13", "7", 
                      "10", "4"), variable = structure(c(1L,  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                          1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                          2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("selected", "new"), class = "factor"), value = c(14.6323031713383, 15.9559892686597, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                  17.8080362595634, 17.9067064016601, 24.0164577112395, 24.8811598509513, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                  26.6357978795688, 26.8956804786175, 29.9814126083425, 32.0991304536091, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                  32.1102536829839, 35.4868462306579, 38.1006034580602, 51.1456293356122, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                  51.3589926258885, 52.1663444535308, 54.5568962268846, 55.046508165816, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                  57.3540750283887, 59.4724704424851, 66.1242468388916, 76.0316429487087, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                  81.2328164785417, 0.852076511173202, 14.5657895883356, 12.879854304722, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                  5.64377267586918, 7.1645313211506, 22.9837800173366, 25.5540168398152, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                  22.2012270424052, 23.9767694081375, 23.8383007367455, 29.8528524241582, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                  35.157323503853, 3.57512478022716, 2.79829414578611, 25.7839377086262, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                  1.61935008218228, 36.4318154009141, 41.9502761903778, 43.6568981148706, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                  50.8270620551394, 25.1245202778254, 17.0173820081843, 32.5450448621647
                                                                                                                                                             )), row.names = c(NA, -46L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Process the data outside the call to `ggplot` to determine the factor order for the grouping variable you are interested in (labels). Then apply this factor to the labels variable in `ggplot`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

sel_order <- 
  data %>% 
  filter(variable == "selected") %>% 
  arrange(desc(value)) %>% 
  mutate(labels = factor(labels))


data %>% 
  mutate(labels = factor(labels, levels = sel_order$labels, ordered = TRUE)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = labels, y = value, fill = variable), group = labels) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=.5, position = "dodge")  +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: It sadly did not work. Thats how far I got as well. See my edit above.

Comment: Could you please paste your data into the question? use `dput(data)` this will make your question reproducible and possible for others to test and verify a solution. The issue is that each dataset has it's own peculiarities.

Comment: I can do it by pre-processing the data outside of the call to `ggplot` to make the `label` variable a factor with the factor order in value sequence.

Comment: You can always upvote the answer if it was helpful!