# sorting stacked bars by highest value of certain rating

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked

I'm trying to sort a stacked barchart object created by `ggplot` by having the item with the highest `"Excellent"` value first. My current code doesn't seem to sort it that way:

```r
R_POPS_testdataset_forstackedbars <- read_csv("R-POPS testdataset forstackedbars.csv") # dataset for testing purposes

RPOPS_ggchart01 <- ggplot(R_POPS_testdataset_forstackedbars, aes(x = Variable_name, y = Rating_prop, fill = factor(Rating, levels=c("Poor","Fair","Good","Very Good","Excellent")))) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position ="fill", width=0.8) + coord_flip() + scale_fill_manual("legend", values = c("Excellent" = "#275E6B", "Very Good" = "#4AAAC4", "Good" = "#8CD4E5", "Fair" = "#F7963D", "Poor" = "#BE2327")) # color scheme for stacked bars
RPOPS_ggchart01 <- RPOPS_ggchart01 + geom_text(aes(label=paste0(sprintf("%1.f", Rating_prop*100),"%")),
                                               position=position_fill(vjust=0.5), color="white", size=9)
```

The above code gets me this:
[image]

My data is structured like this:

```
structure(list(Rating = c("Excellent", "Fair", "Good", "Poor", 
"Very Good", "Excellent", "Fair", "Good", "Poor", "Very Good"
), Variable_name = c("Overall effectiveness of adminstrative support for the program", 
"Overall effectiveness of adminstrative support for the program", 
"Overall effectiveness of adminstrative support for the program", 
"Overall effectiveness of adminstrative support for the program", 
"Overall effectiveness of adminstrative support for the program", 
"Overall effectiveness of your Program Director", "Overall effectiveness of your Program Director", 
"Overall effectiveness of your Program Director", "Overall effectiveness of your Program Director", 
"Overall effectiveness of your Program Director"), Rating_prop = c(0.13, 
0.35, 0.17, 0.13, 0.22, 0.39, 0.09, 0.26, 0.09, 0.17)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Please make your example **reproducible**. This isn't reproducible because your data is shared as a picture of a spreadsheet, not something usable. Could you please post the data as `dput(R_POPS_testdataset_forstackedbars[1:10, ])` (or some other suitable subset), which will be copy/pasteable and include all class and structure information?

Comment: I also edited to remove the font stuff as it didn't seem relevant for the question and could make it harder for people to run your example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ggplot2 bar-chart order by values of one group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62011413/ggplot2-bar-chart-order-by-values-of-one-group)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question and check the answer I had to expand your initial dataset, but it should work with no problem with your original data.

I've used `reorder` + `ave` to reorder the bars. Basically, with `ave` you want to associate the value of `Excellent` to each value of `Variable_name` (even when `Rating` isn't `Excellent`). So that `reorder` knows that the same `Variable_name` value should be treated equally. `replace` is necessary in case you have no `Excellent` value: it just replaces the NA you would have with a zero. Note that I had to `setNames`, that's because I had to select the `Rating_prop` associated with the `Rating` `Excellent`.

```r
# data
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(Variable_name = rep(LETTERS[1:5], each = 5),
                 Rating = c("Poor","Fair","Good","Very Good","Excellent"),
                 Rating_prop = runif(25))
df$Rating_prop <- ave(df$Rating_prop, df$Variable_name, FUN = function(x) x / sum(x))

# library
library(ggplot2)

# solution
ggplot(df, 
       aes(x = Rating_prop,
           y = reorder(Variable_name, ave(setNames(Rating_prop, Rating), Variable_name, FUN = function(x) replace(x["Excellent"], is.na(x["Excellent"]), 0))), 
           fill = factor(Rating, levels=c("Poor","Fair","Good","Very Good","Excellent")))) + 
  geom_col(position ="fill", width = 0.8) +
  scale_fill_manual("legend", values = c("Excellent" = "#275E6B", "Very Good" = "#4AAAC4", "Good" = "#8CD4E5", "Fair" = "#F7963D", "Poor" = "#BE2327")) +
  geom_text(aes(label=scales::percent(Rating_prop, accuracy = 1)),
            position=position_fill(vjust=0.5), color="white", size=9) +
  labs(y = "Variable_name") +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-11-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

I tried to simplify a bit your code:

- I used `scales::percent` instead of `paste`
- I used `geom_col` instead of `geom_bar`, with allows me to remove the `stat = "identity"` argument
- I removed `coord_flip` and I simply switched `x` and `y`

Also, as final touches:

- I added `scale_x_continuous` so to have percentages on the x axis
- I added a `theme`